# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv3.0, opencv

I installed OpenCV and I am not able to find the version of it. I can import cv and it's showing now errors. I am using an ubuntu os.

```
import cv2
cv2.__version__
```

AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute '**version**'.

Comment: You need to install `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: Did you name your script cv2.py?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer guys. I had used the command "pip install opencv-python3" instead of "pip install opencv-python"

Comment: this didnt work for me as `pip` couldn't find a package called `opencv-python3`